# c++ order of precedence - casting before multiplying

Tags: c++, casting, long-integer, operator-precedence

In the C++ function below, why is `numbers[max_index1]` cast to `long long` and then multiplied by `numbers[max_index2]`? I would of thought that you'd multiply the numbers and then cast?

Also would it not make more sense to make the vector numbers type `long long` instead of `int` therefore the casting wouldn't be necessary?

```
long long MaxPairwiseProductFast(const vector<int>& numbers) {

    int n = numbers.size();

    int max_index1 = -1;
    cout << "value at max_index1 is " << numbers[max_index1] << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if((max_index1 == -1) || (numbers[i] > numbers[max_index1]))
            max_index1 = i;


    int max_index2 = -1;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if((numbers[j] != numbers[max_index1]) && ((max_index2 == -1) || (numbers[j] > numbers[max_index2])))
            max_index2 = j;

    return ((long long)(numbers[max_index1])) * numbers[max_index2];
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    long long result = MaxPairwiseProductFast(numbers);
    cout << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isnt it just a case of where you've put the brackets?

Comment: It's casted to long long so the multiplication is done with long long and not int to prevent overflow of int.

Comment: You might think that the cast is expensive, but it's really not. An x86 processor has a special `movsx` instruction (move with sign-extension) that can convert an `int` to a `long long` on the fly, while loading it into position for the multiply. So it is essentially for free.

Comment: One way to clarify this sort of code is to use `static_cast`: instead of `(long long)numbers[max_index1]` (note absence of redundant and confusing parentheses) to `static_cast<long long>(numbers[max_index1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((long long)(numbers[max_index1])) * numbers[max_index2];
```

`numbers[max_index2]` will be promoted to `long long` before multiplication is performed.
If you multiply two `int's` and the result overflowed, there is nothing you can achieve by casting that result to `long long`, so you `cast` first, then multiply.

> Also would be not make more sense to make the vector numbers type long long instead of int therefore the casting wouldn't be necessary?

If you know that the individual numbers will fit an `int`, but the result of multiplying two `int's` can overflow, this will help save space.

Answer (score 1):

> I woudld of thought that you'd multiply the numbers and then cast?

Imagine your two operands have the value `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`. This is the biggest value an `int` can represent, and (since it's a positive integer) the result of squaring this number is *even bigger*.

When you multiply two `int` values, the result is also an `int`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) (specifically conversions, integral promotion and overflow of *signed* types).

Since the result is by definition bigger than the largest value you can store in an `int`, doing this multiplication with `int`s gives an undefined result. You need to perform the multiplication with a type large enough to store the result.